# Exception with running Neo4j version 3 communitiy edition

Tags: neo4j

I unpacked the tar file of Neo4j linux version.
When running the server (./bin start) it seems like the server is up, but I cant access the browser (although I get a message it is ready).
Running the console (./bin console) - returns an error: "Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint"
Did anyone also encountered this issue? How can I solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How did you run `./bin console`? I'm curious since such a thing does not exist.

To start up the database you use `bin/neo4j start` - then you point your browser to localhost:7474.

For command line based access use `bin/neo4j-shell`.